# node js ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal error

Tags: javascript, node.js

whats this problem ????
how should i fix this?

node js crashed with this error
i want execute sql query

```
FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.
 1: 00007FF6C9E25D2F napi_wrap+133327
 2: 00007FF6C9DBF606 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+63062
 3: 00007FF6C9DC049D node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF6CA6ADFB5 v8::V8::ToLocalEmpty+53
 5: 00007FF6C9E518CA node::Encode+58
 6: 00007FF85757A427 node_register_module_v83+226195
 7: 00007FF85757D1AD node_register_module_v83+237849
 8: 00007FF85758D725 node_register_module_v83+304785
 9: 00007FF857577043 node_register_module_v83+212911
10: 00007FF857558154 node_register_module_v83+86208
11: 00007FF857572602 node_register_module_v83+193902
12: 00007FF6C9E86870 uv_timer_stop+736
13: 00007FF6C9E86A47 uv_timer_stop+1207
14: 00007FF6C9E8301B uv_async_send+331
15: 00007FF6C9E827AC uv_loop_init+1292
16: 00007FF6C9E8294A uv_run+202
17: 00007FF6C9D7A345 v8::internal::AsmJsScanner::GetIdentifierString+51749
18: 00007FF6C9DF2E27 node::Start+311
19: 00007FF6C9C4685C RC4_options+339804
20: 00007FF6CAC09388 v8::internal::compiler::RepresentationChanger::Uint32OverflowOperatorFor+14424
21: 00007FF8AAFD7034 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
22: 00007FF8ABD42651 RtlUserThreadStart+33
```

I changed node version . but nothing happen

Comment: Does https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/issues/120#issuecomment-434122985 help?